# Chordal graphs - simple property of a minimal separator

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove the following property concerning separators in chordal graphs:

"Let $G=(V,E)$ be a chordal graph and let $S$ be a minimal $x,y$-separator in $G$ (for nonadjacent vertices $x$ and $y$). Let $C_x$ be the component of $G - S$ that contains $x$. Show that there exists $x' \in C_x$ such that $S \subseteq N(x')$. (note: $N(x')$ is the neighborhood of $x'$ in $G$)."

My approach was a proof by contradiction but I feel like I am going nowhere. I was trying to somehow use other known facts about chordal graphs: the existence of perfect elimination scheme or that $S$ is a clique, but I was unsuccessful. Any tips would be appreciated.